# Calling Soap wanto ExtractValue from CLOB/ returning null

Tags: xml, web-services, oracle11g, xml-parsing

I am new to XML and Clobs. I have read plenty of the posts concerning the subject. I am trying to extract the "processNPCMsgReturn" value from this clob. I am using Oracle 11.2

`

```html
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soap11-enc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <env:Header/>
   <env:Body>
      <ws:processNPCMsgResponse env:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.inpac.telcordia.com/">
         <processNPCMsgReturn>success</processNPCMsgReturn>
         <processNPCMsgReturn1>success1</processNPCMsgReturn1>
         <processNPCMsgReturn1>success2</processNPCMsgReturn2>
      </ws:processNPCMsgResponse>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

```
              -- Create XML type from response text
            l_resp_xml := xmltype.createxml(l_clob_response);
            -- Clean SOAP header
            SELECT extract(l_resp_xml
                          ,'Envelope/Body/node()'
                          ,l_namespace_soap)
              INTO l_resp_xml
              FROM dual;
            -- Extract Fahrenheit value 
            l_result_xml_node := '/processNPCMsgResponse/processNPCMsgReturn/';
            dbms_output.put_line('Response from w3schools webservices:');
            l_result_XML_node := 'processNPCMsgResponse/';
    SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(l_resp_xml, 'processNPCMsgResponse/processNPCMsgReturn', 'xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.inpac.telcordia.com/"') INTO l_response_value FROM dual;
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by following

```
select xmltype( l_clob_response ).extract('//processNPCMsgReturn/text()','xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" ' ||'xmlns:ws="http://ws.inpac.telcordia.com/"').getStringVal() INTO l_response_value1 from dual;
```